# How to send SMS through Asp.net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, sms

How to send SMS from asp.net web application?

Is it necessary to buy from any provider?

Is there any limitation of number of SMS can be sent?

Should sending SMS code be written in different thread so that in case of any exception/delay main thread will not be affected?

Can anybody please provide code sample as well as concept of how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to utilize some sort of telephony provider to achieve this. I personally am a big fan of [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com). They are very reasonable rates and expose an [API](http://www.twilio.com/api) with [language specific API wrappers](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries). .NET in particular has several, including an official one.

Code samples and walkthroughs are available [here](http://www.twilio.com/docs).

The performance impact is minimal, as you essentially construct an XML message that gets passed to a Twilio endpoint. The heavy lifting is off your shoulders as its more a system of passing and receiving XML messages.

Hope that helps, it is a very easy platform to work with.

Answer (score 1):

## here just confiure your online sms provider */ here "way2sms is confiure"

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
 
namespace SMSAPI
{
class SmsSender
{
void send(string uid, string pwd, string no, string msg)
{
String content = "username="+uid+"&password="+pwd;
try
{
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwa.way2sms.com/auth.cl");
request.KeepAlive = false;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.Referer = "http://wwwg.way2sms.com//entry.jsp";
request.Method = "POST";
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
{
cookies.Add(cook);
}
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string serverData = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
content = "custid=undefined&HiddenAction=instantsms&Action=custfrom450000&login=&pass=&MobNo="+no+"&textArea="+msg;
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwa.way2sms.com/FirstServletsms?custid=");
byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Method = "POST";
dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
stream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(stream);
serverData = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwa.way2sms.com/jsp/logout.jsp");
byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Method = "POST";
dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
stream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(stream);
serverData = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
Console.WriteLine("arg exception");
Console.Read();
 
}
catch (WebException e)
{
Console.WriteLine("web exception");
Console.Read();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine("exception");
Console.Read();
}   
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SmsSender sms = new SmsSender();
sms.send("username", "password", "phno_recipient", "message");
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used TcpClient, which implements Disposable & created SmsHelper 
    class

```
public class SmsHelper
{
    public void SendSms(string toNumber, string content)
    {
        bool connected;

        TcpClient smsServer = OpenConnection("xyz.xy.x.xyz", xyzd, out connected);//require ip and port

        if (connected)
        {
            string sms = content; 

            SendSmsToClient(smsServer, Properties.Settings.Default.FromNumber, toNumber, sms);

        }
    }

    protected static TcpClient OpenConnection(string ip, int port, out bool connected)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        string message = string.Empty;

        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        try
        {
            ASCIIEncoding ascEn = new ASCIIEncoding();

            tcpClient.Connect(ip, port);

            Stream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            stream.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            string connect = ascEn.GetString(bb);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(connect))
            {
                //authenticating to smsServer
                string str = "action: login\r\nusername: xxxxx\r\nsecret: integration\r\n\r\n";

                byte[] ba = ascEn.GetBytes(str);
                stream.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                stream.Flush();

                byte[] resp = new byte[100];
                stream.Read(resp, 0, 100);
                response = ascEn.GetString(resp);
                stream.Read(resp, 0, 100);
                message = ascEn.GetString(resp);

                if (response.Contains("Success") && message.Contains("Authentication accepted"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authenticated");
                    stream.Flush();
                    connected = true;
                    return tcpClient;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Credentials error Cant Authenticate");
                    tcpClient.Close();
                    connected = false;
                    return tcpClient;
                }
            }

            connected = false;
            return tcpClient;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        connected = false;
        return tcpClient;
    }

    protected static void CloseConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed process terminated...");
    }


    protected static void SendSmsToClient(TcpClient client, string fromNumber, string toNumber, string smsBody)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        string message = string.Empty;
        string eventMsg = string.Empty;

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Stream stm = client.GetStream();

        string smsSend = string.Format("action: smscommand\r\ncommand: gsm send sms {0} {1} \r\n\r\n", fromNumber, toNumber);

        byte[] smsCmd = asen.GetBytes(smsSend);

        stm.Write(smsCmd, 0, smsCmd.Length);
        stm.Flush();

        byte[] smsResp = new byte[1000];
        stm.Read(smsResp, 0, 1000);
        response = asen.GetString(smsResp);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
        {
            stm.Read(smsResp, 0, 1000);
            message = asen.GetString(smsResp);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                stm.Read(smsResp, 0, 1000);

                eventMsg = asen.GetString(smsResp);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(eventMsg))
                {
                    String[] list = eventMsg.Split('\n');

                    foreach (string value in list)
                    {
                        if (value.StartsWith("--END"))
                        {
                            stm.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```