# Send sms from asp.net (C#) web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending SMS thru Asp.net web application:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051610/sending-sms-thru-asp-net-web-application)

I am new in asp.net web application and i want to send SMS message from asp.net (C#) web application to mobile phone. how can i do? how many way that i can do?

Answer (score 1):

You should contract a service provider to do this, there's no built-in solution. You must find a company that provides this service, which will probably be charged by each message.

This provider will tell you how to consume its service. The most common approach is a REST interface, where you'll post the message and the destination number.

To find this provider it's important to look for companies near your destination number, due to the cost of the operation. So, let's say that you are from England but you're usually sending SMS to people at Italy. This way, it would be better to find a service provider at Italy.

Comment: thank so much for this answer. but now i want to test how to send sms from asp.net web application by using trail service free. now i am using OZEKI NG SMS Gateway. because OZEKI NG SMS Gateway provided free source codes for testing. but during i'm testing, i have some error can not config. do you know other SMS Gateway free service for testing? do you ever test with OZEKI NG SMS Gateway? if not, can you take a time for test it for me? http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=230

Comment: I don't know this provider and no one free neither. I'll take a look at it, but I'd recommend you to open a new question regarding this.

Comment: ok i will open a new question with OZEKI NG SMS Gateway and thanks for your time to take a look OZEKI NG SMS Gateway for me. i'm waiting to see it

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities to get this done is to use the outside web-services that specialize in this since it a telephone network usage

but here are couple of articles

http://www.aswinanand.com/2008/07/send-free-sms-web-service/

http://www.twilio.com/

http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=4&WSID=60

Comment: thanks you for your nice answer and i will try with this. how about OZEKI NG SMS Gateway? do you try it before? for last one week ago, i try with OZEKI NG SMS Gateway with free source code but when i run, it show error message